# Android data send to activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I want to send data from one activity to another activity. However, the activity should not change after sending data.
How can I do this without intent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way is to save data to any place  (SharedPreferencies, DataBase, Json file or even use static variables in special Java class), and to retrieve it in another activity after  it will be launched. Here are appropriate links:

[SharedPreferencies](https://startandroid.ru/en/lessons/535-lesson-33-data-storing-preferences.html)

[Room DataBase](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room)

[Json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40168601/android-how-to-save-json-data-in-a-file-and-retrieve-it)

[Static variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760019/changing-the-value-of-static-variables-in-another-class)

Comment: Hope, it will help!!! Have a happy codding!!!